# New to JSON. How to create a json file when submitting a form and where to view it?

Tags: javascript, html, json

**JSP PAGE:**

```
<form id="login" action="loginaction">
<input type="text" id="username"/>
<input type="text" id="userpass"/>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Basically I want to port a website running on a local sever to mobile. For that i need the mobile application to collect the data from JSON.

Comment: Are you trying to replace Database with Json string/file?

Comment: What is your back end? If you are planing to use any language. For example if you are using PHP or Django python it will be already in dictionary format. You do not need JSON for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

You can use jquery's serialize function for that purpose like this:

```
$('form#login').serialize()
```

It will create query string which can be handled in back end. Official document can be found [here](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/).

If you need actual code for query string to JSON you can use plugin or following function

```
function QueryStringToJSON(query_string) {            
    var pairs = query_string.split('&');

    var result = {};
    pairs.forEach(function(pair) {
        pair = pair.split('=');
        result[pair[0]] = pair[1];
    });

    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result));
}
```

**Note:** In your html you did not set name attribute for inputs. You should set them in order to get query string.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using this jQuery plugin:

https://github.com/marioizquierdo/jquery.serializeJSON

You can use it then like this:

```
$('form#login').on('submit', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var jsonData = $(this).serializeJSON();

    console.log('Submitted data in JSON:', jsonData);

    return false;
});
```